# Get new empty item on model method

Tags: module, magento-1, programming

Collections provide a handy means of getting a blank model - e.g.:

```
$quote->getItemsCollection()->getNewEmptyItem();
```

Is there any means of doing this from an existing model without having to call for the collection - in other words directly from the instance? Something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(43);
$productNew = $product->getNewEmptyItem();
```

I do realize I could call `getCollection()` on the product first - not sure if this has some overhead.

**Edit:**

Obviously `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` produces the desired result. *Obviously*. What I'm looking for is a means of getting a blank object without reinstantiating the model.

Perhaps I just need to switch to using singletons to ease my mind.

Comment: What's the need?

Comment: I'm trying to create dynamic observers that won't necessarily know what the model is before it's retrieved - want a way of getting a blank instance of it without having to reinstantiate. I might be on the wrong track, but this is really handy to know regardless; albeit a #lazyweb way of getting this information!

Comment: I ask because re-instantiation is like *nothing* in terms of processing overhead. And, what are you doing with "dynamic observers"?

Comment: Creating a frontend UI to attach observers to events.

Comment: You may be right about the re-instantiation; but even if it's purely academic it felt like a worthwhile question to ask.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` dynamic events ALWAYS pass the object in via `data_object`. Might indicate an approach for you to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reset();

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)->reset();
```

that calls _clearData, if you check in the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product you can see that this function resets all variables.

Comment: Obviously, yes. I'm curious if there's a way to chain getting a new object at the end of loading. Otherwise, avoid reinstantiating the model again.

Comment: You should be able to use reset(), that calls _clearData, if you check in the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product you can see that this function resets all variables

Comment: Good question by the way, never thought about cleaning up the instance that way

Comment: You can use clone on the model before you load it if you only need empty instances.

Comment: `reset()` only exists for `catalog/product`; is this question not asking for a more generic solution?

Comment: I think the generic function that is shared by most models would be in 'Mage_Core_Model_Abstract' named 'clearInstance()'. But I'm not sure it clears all the data related to a model. Might need some further testing

Comment: @SanderMangel `clearInstance()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @benmarks, hm good to know, I doubt if there is a generic reset function then. Probably best of just unsetting the var with the instance to save memory. that always works

Answer (score 1):

The `reset()` method is available for `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` but as a whole, this isn't available.

You could add a method like this:

```
public function reset() {
    return new self();
}
```

However, you **cannot** then call:

```
$modelInstance->reset();
```

You would have to call:

```
$modelInstance = $modelInstance->reset();
```

Because of this, in my opinion, having your own `reset()` method is going to lead to misuse, and/or may confuse other developers. You are better off doing something like this:

```
$modelInstance = new $modelInstance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work via the `clearInstance` function on `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. This seems to clear references and data plus it also fires an event:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_clear', $this->_getEventData());
```

Maybe I am missing something here though.